# VBA Excel cycle through sheets, find last row in table and autofill with data

Tags: excel, vba, foreach, autofill

I need a script that cycles through all the sheets in a workbook and adds 2 (or more) columns at the end of the table of each sheet (except the first sheet).
In this case I have a YES and NO column to be added.

The added columns YES and NO need to be autofilled all the way down to the end with YES or NO like in the example here below.

[image]

```
Sub LoopSheetsAddDataFilledColumns()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets

Set ws = Sheets(2)

With ws
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    .Columns(LastCol + 1).EntireColumn.Insert
    .Cells(1, LastCol + 1).Value = "YES"
    .Columns(LastCol + 2).EntireColumn.Insert
    .Cells(1, LastCol + 2).Value = "NO"

End With

Next

End Sub
```

The issue is that:

- this script adds only a few columns with YES and NO on the first sheet,
- it doesn't fill the columns all the way to the end,
- It doesn't make exceptions for particular sheets,

Can someone please help update this script? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this modification of your code

```
Sub LoopSheetsAddDataFilledColumns()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets

If ws.Name <> Sheets(1).Name Then
With ws
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    .Columns(LastCol + 1).EntireColumn.Insert
    .Columns(LastCol + 2).EntireColumn.Insert
        
    .Range(.Cells(1, LastCol + 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol + 1)).Value = "YES"
    .Range(.Cells(1, LastCol + 2), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol + 2)).Value = "NO"

End With
End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```vb
Sub LoopSheetsAddDataFilledColumns()

Dim ws As Worksheet, rg As Range
Dim i As Long

For i = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    Set rg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).UsedRange
    With rg
        .Offset(, .Columns.Count).Resize(, 1).Value = "YES"
        .Offset(, .Columns.Count + 1).Resize(, 1).Value = "NO"
    End With
Next

End Sub
```

It loops all sheets from the second one.

It writes next to the `UsedRange` the new columns by using `Offset` and `Resize`. The assumption is that the current data are in a continous range.

Comment: thank you, but this solution unfortunately didn't work for me

Comment: You need to be more specific regarding "didn't work" otherwise I can't help you.

Comment: The fact is that I didn't receive an error but the code also didn't copy the data. However the above solution from Black cat worked well. Thank you again for offering a solution.

Comment: The only issue could be `ThisWorkbook`. If the VBA code is in a different workbook then the one where you want to add the values you have to use `ActiveWorkbook`. It is always better to be explicit instead of implicit (=using `Worksheets` without a preceeding workbook spec)